# Reconnect to Nodejs socket.io Server

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I'm quite new to nodejs and I can't figure out why when I try to connect via Android Smartphone to my Node Js Server I can connect. But when the Webpage isn't closed and the Smartphone is in the LockedScreen Mode, the Device will disconnect and reconnect after a period of time has passed.

So my decision is to disconnect when the window is not active and connect to the server again once it's active.

On the Client side it looks like this.

```
<script src="http://server.xy:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var server = io("http://server.xy:3000");
```

My solution was like that:

```
$(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

    if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
        switch (e.type) {
            case "blur":
                   //disconnect from Server
                break;
            case "focus":
                   //connect to Server
                 break;
         }
    }

    $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by adding on the client side:

```
server.disconnect();
server.connect();
```